# Making html autocomplete only suggest numbers

Tags: html, node.js, angular, autocomplete

So I have an input field that only accepts numbers, but it still suggests strings I have tried to search for previously.
Been searching how I can make it only suggest numbers but have come up empty.

The html code looks like this:

```
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [formGroup]="quickSearchForm"  (keyup.enter)="quickSearch()">
              <input #quickInput
                      type="number"
                      #tooltip="matTooltip"
                      class="filter-input"
                      (focusin)="tooltip.show()"
                      matTooltip="{{ 'order.list.buttons.quick-find-expectations' | translate:locale.language }}.."
                      matTooltipPosition="above"
                      matInput 
                      formControlName="quickSearchId" 
                      placeholder="{{ 'order.list.buttons.quick-find' | translate:locale.language }}.." />
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your main post and add the html code for this input ?
I think that the input is not with type `number`.

Doc reference : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp